# How to use controllerAs (as opposed to $scope) - Actually a Swig/Angular conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn the popular method of using controllerAs as opposed to binding everything to the $scope.  Briefly documented here : http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/

I am going to provide a much simplified example of my code in order to understand how to properly code in this manner.

```
angular
        .module('gc',['gc.login']);

angular
        .module('gc.login',[]);


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
            .module('gc.login')
            .controller('gcLoginController', gcLoginController);

    gcLoginController.$inject = [];

    /* @ngInject */
    function gcLoginController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.blah = "blah";

        activate();

        ////////////////

        function activate() {
            console.log("Hello World!");
        }

    }

})();
```

The code above was created using snippits from the author of the article, but when I try to bind to the variable "blah" in the html, it does not work.  It doesn't output anything at all.

```
<body id="ng-app" ng-app="gc">

<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="gcLoginController as vm">
"{{vm.blah}}"
</div>

</body>
```

This simply outputs ""

Can anyone see what error was made in using this method?

Comment: Those quotes are just there to show me that the code block is working.  If it was working right then it would show "blah"  but right now it just shows ""  meaning that it can't find the variable vm.blah.

Comment: works fine in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ2cThIqnJAJRsaCkWnK?p=preview)

Comment: Does your console log work? I ask because activate gets called before the function is defined. In which case, it could cause an error that causes the controller to cease processing.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? As @charlietfl stated, your code is working properly in a reproduction using Angular 1.4.x

Comment: -Brant The console.log "Hello World!" works.
-Claies I am using 1.4.7

Answer (score 0):

Ah shoot it was a stupid mistake.  Thank you to those who double checked my work in plunker.  I was using a node.js server for this project along with the template engine "Swig".  Apparently that was a mistake to combine Angular and Swig, because they both use {{ }} to bind variables, which is why my code (which as charlietfl pointed out is actually working) didn't seem to work. I will update the title of this post to help others who may have a similarly difficult to trace issue with Angular / Swig.

**Update** - can get around this problem : https://gist.github.com/angelochen960/4188293